# How to restring guest access on Azure AD app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have an ASP .Net Core API running on Azure. I am following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users) to restrict guest access to my API. My understanding was that once `User assignment required` is set to `Yes` on the Enterprise Application, then users not being assigned in the `Users and groups` tab, should get a 401 if trying to access my API - *without any authentication/authorization code on my app*. However, I can still reach that API from my other device or Postman.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please check the app registration, and I think maybe your app is a multi-tenant application.

Comment: when you say you can reach your API from other device or Postman, were you able to make a successful API call? what is the identity the other device is logged in? did you try to call any of your GET api from a browser incognito window?